# Angular Material: how to realize a list like on docs website?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

On Agular Material website (https://material.angularjs.org/#/) there is a lateral bar with a list.
This list has 'accordion-like' feature, clicking on some items expands tyhe list with some subitems, for example clicking on DEMOS will appear a list of available demos.

I'd like to realize this into my webapp, but I'm not able to undertstand which Angular Material components must I use to realize this.

Is there any example?

Comment: I think it's not simply AM components, I think they have added a lot of code, but probably there is extension or something other I don't know to avoid to reinvent the wheel. And "look at the code" is of course NOT an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature will be added in version 0.10.0, you can see progress [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/985).